# Most appropriate setup to share music and playlists accross a network?

Tags: rhythmbox, mp3, ipod, nas, daap

I have a home network with the following setup:

```
A QNAP NAS (has a DAAP server)
A server/media center with XBMC
2 laptops (Linux)
1 desktop (Linux)
Android phone
iPod
```

For a couple of years I haven't been able to find a good solution to my music sharing that allows for the following:

1. Centralized location for music
2. Centralized location for playlists (ie, define the playlist once, be able to play it everywhere)
3. Sync with mobile devices (Android and iPod)

My current setup is having my music on the NAS and either use an NFS share or the built in firefly DAAP to share it. This takes care of 1, but not of 2 and 3.

Do you have any suggestions or set-up ideas for how to achieve 2 and 3? Ideally I'd like to: - Create playlists on my linux laptop/desktops that could then be automatically added anywhere: on that laptop/desktop, on XBMC and iPod/android - Have an easy way of plugging and auto-syncing my iPod and android to either the complete music collection (iPod) or partial (android)

Comment: Can't your NAS DAAP-server handle playlists?

Comment: It's firefly. I think it can only handle them manually (ie, manual creation on the web interface). Also, rhythmbox doesn't see them anyway, nor can one save the playlists on the DAAP share.

Comment: Ubuntu One is one option!?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu One cloud sync for every device and for where ever you are.  First 5GB is free.  Try and see.